# pyqt link list view and table view with model using python dictionary

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt4

I am learning PyQt4 and I am having trouble understanding all the different ways to use Model/View design.

**I have** data in the form of a dictionary that I use to create a model.

The dictionary values are namedtuples that contain 2 lists each.

Each one of those lists, contains row data for a table. An example would look like this:

```
data = { key : ( [ [col1, col2, col3], row2 ], 
                 [ [col1, col2, col3], row2 ] 
       ) }
```

**My goal** is to to have a list view that is a list of all the keys from the dictionary. Clicking on a key in the list view will update the 2 table views with data associated with that key.

**I have working code** but I feel like it's not the best way to do things. **Just for an example, I used a simplified data structure** where the dictionary values are single tables.

I made a model for the list view and a model for the table view that both use the same data. I feel like there's probably a way to use one model for both but I couldn't figure out how to link them and change the displayed values.

My searching has led me to read about proxyModels, dataMappers, itemDelegates, QSortFilterProxyModel, and now TreeViews. But I don't know which to use or how to implement them when my data is a dictionary.

What is the proper way to achieve what I described above?

Do I need to change the data from a dictionary to something else?

Here is the example code I came up with:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import random
import sys

def build_mock_data(num_keys, num_rows=4, num_columns=3):
    result = {}
    key = "key"
    build_row = lambda: [random.randint(0,10) for _ in xrange(num_columns)]
    for i in xrange(num_keys):
        result[key+str(i)] = [build_row() for _ in xrange(num_rows)]
    return result

mock_data = build_mock_data(10)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._data = data
        # defualt key
        self.dict_key = 'key0'

    def set_key(self, key):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.dict_key = key
        self.endResetModel()

    def rowCount(self, QModelIndex_parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self._data[self.dict_key])

    def columnCount(self, QModelIndex_parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self._data[self.dict_key][0])

    def data(self, QModelIndex, int_role=None):
        row = QModelIndex.row()
        column = QModelIndex.column()
        if int_role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data[self.dict_key][row][column])

class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(ListModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._data = sorted(data.keys())

    def list_clicked(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        key = self._data[row]
        table_model.set_key(key)

    def rowCount(self, QModelIndex_parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self._data)

    def data(self, QModelIndex, int_role=None):
        row = QModelIndex.row()
        if int_role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data[row])

    def flags(self, QModelIndex):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable


#########################################
# temporary just to get above code to run
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

list_view = QtGui.QListView()
list_model = ListModel(mock_data)
list_view.setModel(list_model)
list_view.clicked.connect(list_model.list_clicked)
list_view.show()

table_view = QtGui.QTableView()
table_model = TableModel(mock_data)
table_view.setModel(table_model)
table_view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with this approach. In Python 2.7 you might want to use an ordered dict, so the keys behave more like a real list in terms of maintaining item order.

Comment: The keys are conceptualy just a 'list' of items that happen to have a relationship to another list of items - the dictionary values. Using a dict just applies some constraints to the 'list of keys such that they're guaranteed unique, are unordered (use an ordered dict?), etc. It's much like a relational table with one column and a unique constraint, the rows of which map to rows in a second table. There is nothing at all wrong with your solution. It's fine. There's also nothing wrong with having multiple models present the same underlying data in different ways, or layer on top of each other.